# Flask server using asynchronous Rpc client only answer 1 request out of two

Tags: multithreading, flask, rabbitmq, python-multithreading, rpc

I'm trying to implement an async RPC client within a Flask server.
The idea is that each request spawn a thread with an uuid, and each request is going to wait until there is a response in the `RpcClient` `queue` attribute object with the correct `uuid`.

The problem is that one request out of two fails. I think that might be a problem with multi-threading, but I don't see where it comes from.
[Bug can be seen here](https://youtu.be/a8X2upWL0zI).

Using debug print, it seems that the message with the correct uuid is received in the `_on_response` callback and update the `queue` attribute in this instance correctly, but the `queue` attribute within the `/rpc_call/<payload>` endpoint doesn't synchronize (so `queue[uuid]` has a value of `response` in the `RpcClient` callback but still `None` in the scope of the endpoint).

My code:

```py
from flask import Flask, jsonif
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer
import sys
import os
import pika
import uuid
import time
import threading

class RpcClient(object):
    """Asynchronous Rpc client."""
    internal_lock = threading.Lock()
    queue = {}

    def __init__(self):

        self.connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
            pika.ConnectionParameters(host='rabbitmq'))
        self.channel = self.connection.channel()
        self.channel.basic_qos(prefetch_count=1)
        self.channel.exchange_declare(exchange='kaldi_expe', exchange_type='topic')

        # Create all the queue and bind them to the corresponding routing key
        self.channel.queue_declare('request', durable=True)
        result = self.channel.queue_declare('answer', durable=True)

        self.channel.queue_bind(exchange='kaldi_expe', queue='request', routing_key='kaldi_expe.web.request')
        self.channel.queue_bind(exchange='kaldi_expe', queue='answer', routing_key='kaldi_expe.kaldi.answer')
        self.callback_queue = result.method.queue
.
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self._process_data_events)
        thread.setDaemon(True)
        thread.start()

    def _process_data_events(self):
self.channel.basic_consume(self.callback_queue, self._on_response, auto_ack=True)
        while True:
            with self.internal_lock:
                self.connection.process_data_events()
            time.sleep(0.1)

    def _on_response(self, ch, method, props, body):
        """On response we simply store the result in a local dictionary."""
        self.queue[props.correlation_id] = body


    def send_request(self, payload):
        corr_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
        self.queue[corr_id] = None
        with self.internal_lock:
            self.channel.basic_publish(exchange='kaldi_expe',
                                       routing_key="kaldi_expe.web.request",
                                       properties=pika.BasicProperties(
                                           reply_to=self.callback_queue,
                                           correlation_id=corr_id,
                                       ),
                                       body=payload)
        return corr_id


def flask_app():
    app = Flask("kaldi")

    @app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
    def server_is_up():
        return 'server is up', 200

    @app.route('/rpc_call/<payload>')
    def rpc_call(payload):
        """Simple Flask implementation for making asynchronous Rpc calls. """
        corr_id = app.config['RPCclient'].send_request(payload)

        while app.config['RPCclient'].queue[corr_id] is None:
            #print("queue server: " + str(app.config['RPCclient'].queue))
            time.sleep(0.1)

        return app.config['RPCclient'].queue[corr_id]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            rpcClient = RpcClient()
            app = flask_app()
            app.config['RPCclient'] = rpcClient
            print("Rabbit MQ is connected, starting server", file=sys.stderr)
            app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, host='0.0.0.0')
        except pika.exceptions.AMQPConnectionError as e:
            print("Waiting for RabbitMq startup" + str(e), file=sys.stderr)
            time.sleep(1)
        except Exception as e:
            worker.log.error(e)
            exit(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found where the bug came from:

The`debug=True` of the line `app.run(debug=True, threaded=True, host='0.0.0.0')` restart the server at the beginning.

The whole script is then restarted from the beginning. Because of it, another rpcClient is initialized and consume from the same queue. Problem is that the previous thread is also running. This cause two rpcClient to consume from the same thread, with one that is virtually useless.